# Immediately self executing function and "this"

Tags: javascript, scope, execute-immediate

I want to create a javascript library, so I thought making it an immediately self executing function would be a nice thing to do to ensure scope safety and everything.

But now I'm running into a problem with using the "this" keyword that I don't quite understand.

How can I make a code like this work correctly? Currently, it tells me that "image" is undefined.

```
(function() {

    function lib() {
        this.image = document.getElementById("image");
        this.parts = [
            {name: "part1", num: "1"}
        ];

        this.init = function() {
            $(parts).each(function() {
                var partNum = this.num;
                image.getElementById(partNum).addEventListener("click", function() {
                    toggleHighlight(partNum);
                }, true);
            });
        };
    }

    window.lib = new lib();
})();

window.lib.init();
```

How can I access the `image` property?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in a tool like FireBug or Opera DragonFly? Most of the times you can see what the current scope is and what variables are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few issues here:

- you are referencing `parts` in your `init` function without accessing it as a property of `this`.
- within the `each` block, you are accessing `image` as a global variable but it is not declared globally. You can't access `image` from `this` in that block because in that context, `this` is actually set to the item you are iterating on. (That is why you can access `this.num`.)

I sugggest you include var that = this; before your init function and use it when accessing properties like that.image.

```
var that = this;
this.init = function() {
    $(this.parts).each(function() {
        var partNum = this.num;
        that.image.getElementById(partNum).addEventListener("click", function() {
            toggleHighlight(partNum);
        }, true);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you want to get access to `this.image` property defined inside of `lib` function from the anonymous function which you provide to the `each`. To do this you need to preserve `this` to make it available in the anonymous function:

```
this.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    $(parts).each(function() {
        //do something with self.image
        self.image;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also capitalize the first letter of function name `lib` since you are expecting it to be used as a constructor with the `new` keyword.  Take a look at what the author of Javascript The Good Parts has to say about [constructor naming conventions in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names).